# Gnuplot: xtics Labels Interval

Tags: gnuplot, label

I've got a data file with thousands of lines like so:

```
Sat_May_25_09:38:22_2013 9 
Sat_May_25_09:38:35_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:38:55_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:39:30_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:40:25_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:41:21_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:42:16_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:43:11_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:44:07_2013 2 
Sat_May_25_09:45:03_2013 2
```

The first column is for the `xaxis` labels while the second column is for the `yaxis` values. How can I plot this in `xaxis` intervals? For example, in the dataset above, I would want to add only the odd `xaxis` labels but still plot every `yaxis` values. In other words, a range for the `xaxis` labels.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not plot the data using gnuplot's time data and then let gnuplot pick the x-axis positions?

Comment: I changed my time format to the Unix Epoch time, which makes things a lot easier, not only on `gnuplot`, but also on any other program. It is a good standard for date measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a file t.dat

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%b_%d_%H:%M:%S_%Y"
set format x "%d/%m/%y\n%H:%M"
plot "< sed 's/[^_]*_//' t.dat" using 1:2  title "y value"
```

`timefmt` sets the input time format. Unfortunately, the day name isn't a recognised value, so the `"< sed 's/[^_]*_//' t.dat"` redirects the output of a `sed` command, which strips the day and first underscore, as input.

`format` set the output to date newline time, change this to get the format you want.

Comment: I've actually found out about that unrecognizable format of `timefmt`, which is kinda a drawback. Nevertheless, your answer provided input regarding that `sed` piping. Very interesting.